# Cholesky decomposition of large matrices

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, python, cholesky-decomposition

I am trying to obtain the Cholesky decomposition of a huge $150,000 \times 150,000$ *sparse* matrix with randomly distributed non-zero elements. I have only the entries for which the values are non-zero.

I tried using the sparse Cholesky decomposition from SciPy library but it gave me an error of not enough memory. Any suggestions for efficient ways to proceed with the Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: If no one answers, delete and repost at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Might this result help you break down the problem into smaller pieces? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221804/cholesky-factorization-with-submatrices

Comment: Do you really need the Cholesky decomposition? Or is it meant to be used for another operation?

Comment: If I am not mistaken it takes about 90 GB to store a symmetric matrix of that size. Too large for typical RAMs. I would implement myself in python the simple [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms) which works through the matrix ***line by line*** thereby reading and writing each line from/to a file.